# Find how many times the largest digit appears in an array

Tags: c

I have no idea what's wrong with the function goes by the name "`int Count_largest_even`". It's supposed to take the largest digit found in the given array (by the function "`int find`") and find how many times the digit appears in the array.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int Count_largest_even(int size, int *array, int large);
void ArrayPrint(int a[], int size);
int find(int array[], int size);
int arr1[16] = { 2, 22, 1, 3, 24, 94, 93, 12, 12, 66666, 21, 24, 8888, 21, 2, 33 };

int main() {
    int mount;
    int even;
    ArrayPrint(arr1,16);

    even = find(arr1, 16);
    mount = Count_largest_even(16, arr1, even);
    printf("\n The biggest even digit is : %d\n   %d", even,mount);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int find(int array[], int size){
    int i = 0, digit, edigit = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){

        while (array[i]!=0)
        {
            digit = abs(array[i] % 10);
            if (digit > edigit)//checking condition for large
            {
                if (digit % 2 == 0)
                {
                    edigit = digit;
                }
            }
            array[i] = array[i] / 10;
        }
    }

    return edigit;
}

void ArrayPrint(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}

int Count_largest_even(int size, int *array, int large)
{
    int i;
    int count = 0, digit;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        while ((array[i]!=0))
        {
            digit = abs(array[i] % 10);
            if (digit == large)
            {
                count++;
            }

            array[i] = array[i] / 10;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger before, now is the perfect time to learn it. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring the variables and their values. It should help you find problems like this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude excuse me for the unsubstantial response, but I've run the debugger several times prior to posting the question and the key phrase here is " I have no idea what's wrong with the function " meaning I know where my code fails but I do not see how I can improve it . What I can add is that if I make a local array in the function count_largest_even and replace it with the rest of the code in that function it will work properly.

Comment: @KrammedVl, please, edit your question to add what you have tested and maybe what output you get and if possible what output you are expected ?

Comment: @KrammedVl Try changing functions `find` and `Count_largest_even` so that they do not modify the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ian Abbott said, you should not modify the array inside your loop.

But you can also do this in a single pass - some pseudo code:

```
int count = 0;
int largest_digit = 0;

for each digit:
   if(digit > largest_digit) {
      largest_digit = digit;
      count = 1;
   }
   else if(digit == largest_digit)
      count++;
```